# post value of selected item in drop down

Tags: python, flask

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
import requests
import json

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def fill_devices():
    devices = requests.request("GET", "http://10.64.127.94:5000/api/get_platforms", headers={}, data="").json()["final_result"]
    return render_template('devices.html', devices=devices)

@app.route('/submit_device', methods = ['POST'])
def submit_device():
    # get the device name here
    labels = requests.request("GET", "http://10.64.127.94:5000/api/get_labels", headers={},
              data=json.dumps(
                  { "device": ""}
              )).json()["final_result"]
    return render_template('labels.html', labels=labels)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True, port=5000)
```

labels.html

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block devices %}
        <select name="device_id">
            <option>SELECT</option>
            {% for device in devices %}
            <option>{{ device }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
{% endblock devices %}
```

When someone changes the value in drop down, I should get that in app.py so that I can fill the other drop down and render. How to achieve this?

Comment: You could simply use `request.form.get` function for getting post form-data in the handler function. Getting device_id like `request.form.get('device_id')`  should work.

Answer (score 0):

You'd also need to import request from flask library for getting request body. use `request.form.get("<form-field-name>")` for getting form field.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, flash, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
import requests
import json

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def fill_devices():
    devices = requests.request("GET", "http://10.64.127.94:5000/api/get_platforms", headers={}, data="").json()["final_result"]
    return render_template('devices.html', devices=devices)

@app.route('/submit_device', methods = ['POST'])
def submit_device():
    # get the device name here
    labels = requests.request("GET", "http://10.64.127.94:5000/api/get_labels", headers={},
              data=json.dumps(
                  { "device": request.form.get("device_id")}
              )).json()["final_result"]
    return render_template('labels.html', labels=labels)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True, port=5000)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but the request itself is not coming to the flask route when I change something in the first drop down
@app.route('/submit_device', methods = ['POST'])